# Free venue for advertising a funded PhD opportunity?

Tags: phd, funding

I am trying to advertise a PhD opportunity in Sciences. So far, I have tried some relevant groups and email lists, as well as my own social media accounts. As I don't have a huge number of followers, my posts have not attracted a lot of relevant candidates.

I thought of *findaphd.com*, but then I found that their prices are very expensive.

I was wondering if there are other similar free or cheap relevant venues for advertising my PhD project? If so, which ones?

Comment: At this level of detail and precision, the answer is "yes".

Comment: @tripleee Which ones? Sorry if I was not being precise enough for you.

Comment: It obviously depends on the field and the topic, which you have not revealed.

Comment: @FundedPhD Why do you react like this? Their comment is extremely relevant and not rude at all. I believe there are such venues for some specific fields. Just edit your question and add the missing information.

Comment: Have you tried your university's web site? Or your department's web site? If they don't have such, they might like to start. When I want to know about a uni their web site is often where I start.

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest, and often best, venue to advertise for a PhD student is within your home institute. That way you have people that are already in the city, available to look around, probably have reliable recommendations from their teachers (your colleagues) and they are already being taught the speciality of institute X. Put fliers up around your department common areas if you have a noticeboard or something, send emails through departmental mailing lists (if your institute allows it) and try to hit groups on social media.
Also, don't underestimate personal connections. Ask colleagues if they know anyone looking to do a PhD in X.

Comment: Not only your home institute, but in particular your own circle. If you are at the point in your career, where you can advertise Phd opportunities, you will certainly have collaborators and close colleagues who currently work at other universities. So send them a short note and the advertisement. If they just put it on their local noticeboard or mailing list, this already helps advertising to the right people, but they might also know some good candidates more directly.

Comment: Great addition @mlk . I think people underestimate the power of word of mouth.